# Combine multiple cb.literal() into 1 expression

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am working on a Spring Boot project that uses PostgreSQL. I want to create an advanced search feature where user can search through the jsonb column that I have in many of my tables.

Somewhere in my Specification class, I have this code:

```
...
String stringToSearch = searchCriteria.getValue().toString().toLowerCase();
String filterKey = searchCriteria.getFilterKey();
Expression<String> columnPath;
if(filterKey.contains(".")){
   columnPath = root.get(filterKey.substring(0, filterKey.indexOf(".")));
   System.out.println(filterKey.substring(filterKey.indexOf(".")+1));
   String[] jsonPaths = (filterKey.substring(filterKey.indexOf(".")+1)).split("\\.");
   Expression<String> totalJsonPath = cb.literal(jsonPaths[0]);
   for(String jsonPath: jsonPaths){
       totalJsonPath = cb.and(totalJsonPath, cb.literal(jsonPath));
   }
   columnPath = cb.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", String.class, columnPath, totalJsonPath);
   } else {
       columnPath = root.get(filterKey);
   }
    switch(Objects.requireNonNull(SearchOperation.getSimpleOperation(searchCriteria.getOperation()))){
            case CONTAIN:
                return cb.like(columnPath, "%" + stringToSearch + "%");
            case DOES_NOT_CONTAIN:
                return cb.notLike(columnPath, "%" + stringToSearch + "%");
            ...
```

I want it this way because then user can search deep inside the jsonb, e.g.:

```
"jsonCol":{   
   "jsonKey": {
      "jsonNestedKey" : "my_value"
   }
}
```

I know my code above does not work because `cb.and()` is not for this purpose.
What I want to achieve is:

```
columnPath = cb.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", 
String.class, 
columnPath, 
cb.literal(jsonPaths[0]), 
cb.literal(jsonPaths[1])
);
```

While chaining 2 "jsonb_extract_path_text" function with `cb.and()` defeats the purpose, I have also tried nesting 2 "jsonb_extract_path_text" functions inside of each other but PostgreSQL does not understand what I am trying to do.